# Write output to a file as well as showing it in my notebook

Tags: output-formatting

I know this is a bit vague, but I will try to be as specific as I can.
Basically, I am looking for a way to save formatted output, like [`sink`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html) in R and [`writeto`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=writeto) in Maple.

Basically, I use [`printf`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=printf) (Maple) to format everything, and it saves to a file. Anything that is not produced by `printf` will not be save to the file, like a plot.

Heres is an example that gives an idea of what I am looking for:

```
mybigcode[x_, y_, z_] := Module[
   {pars, numpars, numparsse, tmp, res, niceoutput},

   pars = {f0, p, mu, sigma, alpha, beta};
   numpars = Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 6], 0.01];
   numparsse = Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 6], 0.01];
   tmp = {#1, "=", #2, "(", #3, ")"} & @@@ 
     Transpose[{pars, numpars, numparsse}];


   res = OpenWrite["test.txt"];
   Print["Here is the result:"];
   niceoutput = Grid[tmp, Alignment -> {Left, Center}];
   Print["Other information....."];

   Write[res, niceoutput];
   Close[res];

   myplot = Plot[Sin[t], {t, -10, 10}];
   Export["myplot.pdf", myplot];
]

mybigcode[1, 2, 3]
```

I want a text file with this content:

```
Here is the result:
f0      = 0.77  ( 0.28 )
p       = 0.38  ( 0.68 )
(* the nice formatted 'grid' *)
Other information.....
```

Basically, I want to do some calculating, format it, show on results on the screen and also save them all to a text file.

AND, if possible, I want the last `Plot[]` to be shown in the Notebook as well as save to the PDF file. And, possibly, those what is sent to the text file should be shown (printed) as well in the notebook.

Here is a screenshot (from my Maple code using `printf`)

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in *Mathematica*? What's the command to use?

Comment: Random unhelpful comment: have you tried TableForm?

Comment: @barrycarter  I believe that only prints the result to notebook. Each print will shown as a separate cell. What I really want, is to simple write them to a text file, so it's easy to copy and paste as it is. Thanks.

Comment: `OpenWrite["/tmp/output.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm]` does the magic. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097172/